# How to run sh scripts by Chef and show echo output

Tags: bash, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm having a problem with Chef and sh script. My sh script doing a few things and for each step, it echoes a message that something was done successfully or not. I want run this script in Chef, but it doesn't work and I can't see anything in the logs except that script was run with success which is not true. Here is how I'm doing this:

```
cookbook_file "/tmp/myLib.rpm" do
source "myLib.rpm"
mode '0775'
action :create
end

cookbook_file "/tmp/install.sh" do
    source "install.sh"
    mode '0755'
    action :create
end

execute "installing my lib" do
    command "sh /tmp/install.sh"
    user 'root'
    live_stream true
    action :run
end
```

The script is done with success, but inside log I can see only:

```
Loading cookbooks [security@0.0.1]
INFO: *** Chef 12.18.31 ***
INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/security/recipes/install-mylib.rb in the cache.
INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/security/metadata.rb in the cache.
INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/security/files/default/install.sh in the cache.
INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/security/files/default/myLib.rpm in the cache.
INFO: Processing cookbook_file[/tmp/myLib.rpm] action create (security::install-mylib line 1)
INFO: Processing cookbook_file[/tmp/install.sh] action create (security::install-mylib line 7)
INFO: cookbook_file[/tmp/install.sh] created file /tmp/install.sh
INFO: cookbook_file[/tmp/install.sh] updated file contents /tmp/install.sh
INFO: cookbook_file[/tmp/install.sh] mode changed to 755
INFO: Processing execute[installing my lib] action run (security::install-mylib line 13)
INFO: execute[installing my lib] ran successfully
```

I can't see any echo from install.sh and work from this script is not done. When I run this script directly on the machine, everything work.

Any help or ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the `log_level` set to?

Comment: `log_level` is set to debug

Answer (score 0):

A better option to run a script would be to use the [script resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/script/). Although `execute` resource should also work just fine.

Try running your script with the `script` resource, like below:

```rb
script 'installing my lib' do
  code '/tmp/install.sh'
  user 'root'
  interpreter 'bash'
  action :run
end
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result - all steps run in success but job from the script is not done :(